# Does the $n$-order derivative $\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ have a general expression?

Tags: derivatives

Does the $n$-order derivative $\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ have a general expression, e.g. $\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g^{2}(x)}$ when $n=1$?

Comment: The $n$-th order derivative of a product $F(x)G(x)$ has a general expression, looking like the binomial theorem: $(FG)^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}F^{(k)}G^{(n-k)}$.  Now set $F = f$ and $G = 1/g$.

Comment: Nice comments! Thank you, bro. @KCd

Comment: [See this article on the General Leibniz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)

Comment: «Thanks bro, @Kcd» ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Mark Viola is correct about using the General Leibniz Rule but in our case this will also have to be combined with Faà di Bruno's formula $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(g(x)) = \sum \frac{n!}{m_1!1^{m_1}m_2!2^{m_2}...m_n!n^{m_n}} f^{(m_1+...+m_n)}(g(x)) \cdot \Pi_{j=1}^n (g^{(j)}(x))^{m_j}$$ to get a formula purely in terms of $f$ and $g$ (Faà di Bruno's  will expand the $(g^{-1})^{(k)}$ bit).